# WordSearch: A love of making things

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes *the love for making, building or creating things*. What would be the best word for this?

Thanks.

PK

Comment: _Creativeness_ has the 'enthusiasm' connotations.

Comment: These days, the people themselves are called [makers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maker_culture). Their defining characteristic might be termed an *inventive bent*.

Comment: Someone who enjoys making things is often referred to as crafty, arty, or even artsy-craftsy. The first needs to be used with caution owing to its more common rather negative meaning, but works if there is sufficient context. I also didn't notice the word craftsman mentioned in other answers/comments. Although not a word for the love of making things per se, it could well be applied to the one who loves making things.

Answer (score 2):

Such a person might be called a *bricoleur* if they use *bric-a-brac* to make the things, or whatever is at hand.

Answer (score 1):

How about these?

**Centophilia**

> The love of new things or ideas.

**Ideophilia**

> The love of ideas.

Source: [List of philias](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/philias.html)

Comment: That's very close. All we now need is to find a word that means 'love of making things' and we can combine them into the word we are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an exact match for this. "Creativity" is probably closest, as it denotes a facility for creation and connotes an enjoyment of doing so. You would never describe a person as creative who was good at making things, but didn't enjoy it. "Ingenuity" and "ingeniousness" also come to mind, more in the realm of invention, but implying perhaps a little more strongly than "creativity" a zest for making things.

Comment: Creativity denotes facility without regard to love or passion. Ingenious sounds closer. I was looking for something with ends in 'philia'.

Comment: You should probably add that criterion to the question, then, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

[Artistry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artistry) may suggest passion and ability for what you are creating:

> - artistic ability or skill
> - quality that results from artistic ability or skill

(M-W)

Answer (score 0):

DIY enthusiast? Still not a single word!

Comment: No. Not a word. ;-)

Comment: I figured as much but couldn't stop from answering

Comment: A bit of a mouthful, no? ;-)